# Are raw data provided by tshark full?

Tags: python, wireshark

Because display filters are not supported when saving captured data with tshark
I am trying to create valid cap file that I can read in Wireshark.

I capture data with

> tshark -i wlan2 -V -x -q -Y "radiotap.channel.freq > 2400 && radiotap.channel.freq < 2500"

In python I am scraping raw data with:

```
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(tshark_process.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
   substring = oneline[5:53]    
   clean = ''.join([c for c in substring if 34 < ord(c) < 127])    
   raw_packet += clean
```

I am converting these data back to raw hex data:

```
newFile = open("filename.cap", "wb")
newFile.write(bytes.fromhex(raw_packet))
```

I also tried:

```
newFile.write(bytearray(binascii.unhexlify(raw_packet)))
```

or

```
newFile.write(binascii.unhexlify(raw_packet))
```

But when I open the filename.cap in Wireshark I don't see normal packet data:

[image]

> Frame 1: 260 bytes on wire (2080
>   bits), 260 bytes captured (2080 bits)
>       Encapsulation type: JavaScript Object Notation (175)
>       Frame Number: 1
>       Frame Length: 260 bytes (2080 bits)
>       Capture Length: 260 bytes (2080 bits)
>       [Frame is marked: False]
>       [Frame is ignored: False]
>       [Protocols in frame: json:data-text-lines] JavaScript
>   Object Notation Line-based text data
>   (1 lines)
>        [truncated]\000\000 \000\256@\000\240 \b\000\240
>   \b\000\000\020\002l\t\240\000\336\000d\000\000\000\000\000\000\001\200\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\377\264\373\344J\352\346\264\373\344J\352\346p!\200\201+A'\000\000\000d\0001\004\000\

Are raw data provided by tshark full?

How can I convert them back to Wireshark readable file?

Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Capture Formats

Packet captures are file formats that organize packets along with metadata. There are two formats that are primarily used by the *shark family:

- [pcap](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat): Format popularized by tcpdump, which is based on [libpcap](https://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html)
- [pcapng](http://xml2rfc.tools.ietf.org/cgi-bin/xml2rfc.cgi?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcapng/pcapng/master/draft-tuexen-opsawg-pcapng.xml&modeAsFormat=html/ascii&type=ascii): Modern format that supports saving more metadata (like packet statistics, interface names, capturing OS, etc.) By default, *shark saves to this format.

If you want a visual on the file bytes of a pcap, including file header, [this article](https://tshark.dev/formats/pcap_deconstruction/) deconstructs a capture with 2 ARP packets.

### Python & Packets

There are many python parsers to create capture files that can be read by Wireshark. The most versatile one is [Scapy](https://scapy.net), which is used to both read and generate packets. You can read and write to a pcap without worrying about the file header:

#### Generate Traffic

First generate a 1 packet file with tshark:

```sh
tshark -w example.pcap -c 1
```

#### Read Capture

Then read with scapy. Here we use the Scapy interpreter that extends the Python interpreter. You can do the same thing in a script by prefacing it with `from scapy.all import *`. Note that Scapy provides many more tools to manipulate packets.

```py
>>> capture = rdpcap("example.pcap")
>>> len(capture)
1
>>> for pkt in capture:
...:     pkt.show()
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
  src= ac:86:74:a9:56:42
  type= 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version= 4
     ihl= 5
     tos= 0x20
     len= 60
     id= 0
     flags= DF
     frag= 0
     ttl= 55
     proto= tcp
     chksum= 0x1abd
     src= 17.253.17.209
     dst= 10.255.250.18
     \options\
###[ TCP ]###
        sport= http
        dport= 50653
        seq= 616207835
        ack= 2603062618
        dataofs= 10
        reserved= 0
        flags= SA
        window= 28880
        chksum= 0x21e6
        urgptr= 0
        options= [('MSS', 1456), ('SAckOK', b''), ('Timestamp', (4160359186, 
1059821791)), ('NOP', None), ('WScale', 8)]
```

#### Write Capture

Writing back to pcap is similarly simple:

```py
>>> wrpcap('written.pcap', capture)
```

#### Verification

Checking that Tshark can read the generated `written.pcap`, we see that it can:

```sh
$ tshark -r written.pcap
    1   0.000000 usscz2-vip-bx-009.aaplimg.com → 10.255.250.18 TCP  74 http(80) → 50653 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=28880 Len=0 MSS=1456 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=4160359186 TSecr=1059821791 WS=256 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7 ← ac:86:74:a9:56:42
```

Comment: Note you can also do the capture from within Scapy with `sniff()` then `wrpcap` (see the great answer above)

Comment: @Ross Jacobs Thank you very much for your great answer, but my problem is, that I can not use `tshark -w` option because I need to use more WiFi adapters with different frequencies filter and frequency filter is just display filter, that can not be combined with `-w` option. So I need to check manually packet and if it has right frequency then write readable raw data.

Comment: If your complete tshark command is relevant, you may want to add it to your question.

Comment: @Vladimír Mentioning in case it doesn't register as a notification

Comment: This is my complete tshark command `tshark -i wlan2 -V -x -q -Y "radiotap.channel.freq > 2400 && radiotap.channel.freq < 2500"`

Comment: So use a pipe: `dumpcap -i wlan2 -w - | tshark -r - "radiotap.channel.freq > 2400 && radiotap.channel.freq < 2500" -w filtered.pcap`. Dumpcap, which captures packets in most cases, is dumb and doesn't understand display filters. Tshark can read display filters as long as long as its not explicitly capturing (this seems to be more like a vestige of tcpdump than a problem implementing it).